# Trying to understand URLSession dataTask cacheing

Tags: ios, swift, caching, nsurlsessiondatatask, urlsession

I am downloading images from a website using the code below that caches images. Do I need to store images in the apps directory to permanently save them?

After running this code, I can turn my device on airplane mode, restart it, and open the app and the images are still there. Which I'm confused by. I thought cacheing was only temporary? Where is this image being saved, and most importantly for how long?

I've read Apple's URL Session Programming Guide and it did not answer these questions.

---

```
func getImageFromWeb(_ urlString: String, closure: @escaping (UIImage?) -> Void) {
    guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
        return closure(nil)
    }

    let task = URLSession(configuration: .default).dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        guard error == nil else {
            print("error: \(String(describing: error))")
            return closure(nil)
        }
        guard response != nil else {
            print("no response")
            return closure(nil)
        }
        guard data != nil else {
            print("no data")
            return closure(nil)
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            closure(UIImage(data: data!))
        }
    }; task.resume()
}
```

Function Call:

```
getImageFromWeb("http://www.apple.com/euro/ios/ios8/a/generic/images/og.png") { (image) in
    if let image = image {
        // Do something with image
    }
}
```